# Using grep to search a string with a star(*)

Tags: file, unix, printing, grep, command

I have two filees and I am trying to print all those lines from file1 which are not present in file 2 
I am using command 
grep -v -f file 2 file 1

It is working in all the cases but it behaves weirdly when file 2 has any * in the line. Please tell me what is the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` interprets its pattern as a regular expression, so `*` means repetition of the previous character (or subexpression). Use `grep -F` to get rid of this behavior.

Comment: You mean to say grep -F -f file 2 file 1

Comment: @Aarav indeed. Or use `fgrep`, which is the same as `grep -F`.